# RStudio GIT on windows using network drives

Tags: git, rstudio

I would like to use a network drive on windows instead of `github.com` when using RStudio for version control.

I have a team of colleagues who write code in RStudio, and I would like to start using version control to start pushing and pulling code up in an organised and controlled manner.

Rstudio requires a URL which ends with `.git` which makes sense when using github but when I try and replace it with something like file://T:\path\to\folder.git, it says it doesn't exit or I don't have the correct access rights despite being able to open and modify everything in the network drive.

where T:\ is the network drive that all my colleagues have access to.

Can someone give me a bit of a walk through in terms of how to set up an R project to that version control can work effectively.

Comment: Did you try `file:///T:/path/to/folder.git`?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the **[local protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html#Local-Protocol)** for Git, the path should be:

```
T:\\path\\to\\folder.git
# or
file:///T:/path/to/folder.git? –  VonC 1 hour ago
```

Each time, you can quickly change the origin path with:

```
git set-url origin T:\\path\\to\\folder.git
git set-url origin file:///T:/path/to/folder.git
```

The Pro Git book adds:

> Git operates slightly differently if you explicitly specify `file://` at the beginning of the URL.
>
> - If you just specify the path, Git tries to use hardlinks or directly copy the files it needs.
> - If you specify `file://`, Git fires up the processes that it normally uses to transfer data over a network which is generally a lot less efficient method of transferring the data.
>     The main reason to specify the `file://` prefix is if you want a clean copy of the repository with extraneous references or objects left out – generally after an import from another version-control system or something similar (see [Chapter 10 for maintenance tasks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Maintenance)).
>
> We’ll use the normal path here because doing so is almost always faster.